# MSYS2 Correct way to download and build dependency

Tags: mingw-w64, msys2, msys

I'm new with MSYS2 and struggle to download and build [angleproject dependency](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/?h=mingw-w64-angleproject). Can you help me and write in steps how to build it offline on win7?
Thanks in advance.